# Not able to acces public variable (returns null)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, javascript

I'm quite new at programming and I'm facing an issue where i'm not able to acces a public variable from a contract.

In the contract, I've declared following public variable:

`uint public numFoodInfos;`

In JS I try to call this variable:

```
contractAdressF2F = "...";
ABIArrayF2F = ...;
dataF2F = "...";
myContractF2F = web3.eth.contract(ABIArrayF2F).at(contractAdressF2F);

myContractF2F.numFoodInfos.call(function (error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.toNumber())
    else
        console.log(error);
});
```

However, this returns 'null'.

Anyone sees the problem here? I read that public variables should generate a getter function automatically.

FYI, I'm using the meteor framework. Other custom functions of the same contract do work...

Answer (score 4):

Try calling that variable using parenthesis like this -

```
myContractF2F.numFoodInfos().call(function (error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.toNumber())
    else
        console.log(error);
});
```

The reason why we need to add parenthesis is explained here - https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions
(When you make a state variable public, the compiler automatically generates a getter function as described in the documentation)

Comment: I've added the parenthesis as you suggested, but then I get the following error:
inpage.js:217 Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.